# how to get the array key values and count the values in one array object

Tags: php, arrays

I have doubt in php arrays get the array key value and count the same key repeated in php array.
Here am posting my array object output through the one variable am getting this data.
Here my requirement is in this array i have [room_type] and [meal_type].

> Here [room_type] => APARTMENT ONE BEDROOM  is 3 times came in this
>   array. so my required result is  3 x APARTMENT ONE BEDROOM  Here
>   [room_type] => APARTMENT TWO BEDROOM  is 2 times came in this array.
>   so my required result is  2 x APARTMENT TWO BEDROOM  Here [room_type]
>   => APARTMENT THREE BEDROOM  is 1 time came in this array. so my required result is 1 x APARTMENT THREE BEDROOM

```
$room_details =  
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4508
            [api] => hotelbeds
            [room_no] => 1
            [room_type] => APARTMENT ONE BEDROOM
            [meal_type] => ONE ROOM
            [updated_on] => 2019-01-16 13:03:17
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4509
            [room_no] => 2
            [room_type] => APARTMENT TWO BEDROOM
            [meal_type] => TWO ROOMS
            [updated_on] => 2019-01-16 13:03:09
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4510
            [room_no] => 3
            [room_type] => APARTMENT ONE BEDROOMS
            [meal_type] => TWO ROOMS
            [updated_on] => 2019-01-16 13:03:38
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4511
            [room_no] => 3
            [room_type] => APARTMENT TWO BEDROOMS
            [meal_type] => TWO ROOMS
            [updated_on] => 2019-01-16 13:03:38
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4512
            [room_no] => 3
            [room_type] => APARTMENT THREE BEDROOMS
            [meal_type] => THREE ROOMS
            [updated_on] => 2019-01-16 13:03:38
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4513
            [room_no] => 3
            [room_type] => APARTMENT ONE BEDROOMS
            [meal_type] => ONE ROOM
            [updated_on] => 2019-01-16 13:03:38
        )
)
```

This result i want to show in One div tag like this.

```
<div class="roomtype">
<p>
3 x APARTMENT ONE BEDROOM
2 x APARTMENT TWO BEDROOM
1 x APARTMENT THREE BEDROOM
</p>
</div>
```

And [meal_type] => ONE ROOM  came in this array 2 times so result is 2 x ONE ROOM 
[meal_type] => TWO ROOMS  came in this array 3 times so result is 3 x TWO ROOMS
[meal_type] => THREE ROOMS  came in this array 1 time so result is 1 x THREE ROOMS
This result i want to show in Another Div Tag like this .

```
<div class="mealtype">
<p>
2 x ONE ROOM 
3 x TWO ROOMS
1 x THREE ROOMS
</p>
</div>
```

I tried below code not working , can any one please help on this.

```
                                        For Meal Type 
                                        --------------
                                        $countedValues = array_count_values($room_details->meal_type);
                                        //Build strings from value and display them.
                                        foreach( $countedValues as $roomType=>$count ){
                                            echo $count . ' x ' . $Mealtype . '<br />';
                                        }

                                        For Room Type 
                                        --------------
                                        $countedValues = array_count_values($room_details->room_type);
                                        //Build strings from value and display them.
                                        foreach( $countedValues as $roomType=>$count ){
                                            echo $count . ' x ' . $roomType . '<br />';
                                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello [Niranjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10765955/niranjan),

you can iterate through your array and count this data as followed,

```
<?php
$room_details = array(
    array(
        "id" => 4508, 
        "api" => "hotelbeds",
        "room_no" => 1,
        "room_type" => "APARTMENT ONE BEDROOMS",
        "meal_type" => "ONE ROOM",
        "updated_on" => "2019-01-16 13:03:17"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 4509,
        "room_no" => 2,
        "room_type" => "APARTMENT TWO BEDROOMS",
        "meal_type" => "TWO ROOMS",
        "updated_on" => "2019-01-16 13:03:09"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 4510,
        "room_no" => 3,
        "room_type" => "APARTMENT ONE BEDROOMS",
        "meal_type" => "TWO ROOMS",
        "updated_on" => "2019-01-16 13:03:38"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 4511,
        "room_no" => 3,
        "room_type" => "APARTMENT TWO BEDROOMS",
        "meal_type" => "TWO ROOMS",
        "updated_on" => "2019-01-16 13:03:38"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 4512,
        "room_no" => 3,
        "room_type" => "APARTMENT THREE BEDROOMS",
        "meal_type" => "THREE ROOMS",
        "updated_on" => "2019-01-16 13:03:38"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 4513,
        "room_no" => 3,
        "room_type" => "APARTMENT ONE BEDROOMS",
        "meal_type" => "ONE ROOM",
        "updated_on" => "2019-01-16 13:03:38"
    )
);

$room_types = [];
$meal_types = [];

foreach($room_details as $k => $v) {
    if(!array_key_exists($v["room_type"], $room_types)) {
        $room_types[$v["room_type"]] = 1;
    } else {
        $room_types[$v["room_type"]] = $room_types[$v["room_type"]] + 1;
    }

    if(!array_key_exists($v["meal_type"], $meal_types)) {
        $meal_types[$v["meal_type"]] = 1;
    } else {
        $meal_types[$v["meal_type"]] = $meal_types[$v["meal_type"]] + 1;
    }
}

print_r($room_types);
print_r($meal_types);
?>
```

Now you can access those arrays to fetch count.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
<?php

$room_details = array(
    (object)array(
                'id' => 4508,
                'api' => 'hotelbeds',
                'room_no' => 1,
                'room_type' => 'APARTMENT ONE BEDROOM',
                'meal_type' => 'ONE ROOM',
                'updated_on' => '2019-01-16 13:03:17'
        ),

    (object)array(
                'id' => 4509,
                'room_no' => 2,
                'room_type' => 'APARTMENT TWO BEDROOM',
                'meal_type' => 'TWO ROOMS',
                'updated_on' => '2019-01-16 13:03:09'
        ),

    (object)array(
                'id' => 4510,
                'room_no' => 3,
                'room_type' => 'APARTMENT ONE BEDROOM',
                'meal_type' => 'TWO ROOMS',
                'updated_on' => '2019-01-16 13:03:38'
        ),
);

$countedValues = array_count_values(
     array_map(function($x){
                return $x->meal_type;
      },$room_details)
 );

 //Build strings from value and display them.
foreach( $countedValues as $mealtype=>$count ){
        echo $count . ' x ' . $mealtype . '<br />';
}
```

sample output:

```
1 x ONE ROOM<br />
2 x TWO ROOMS<br />
```

you can try both examples on [online PHP REPL](https://repl.it/repls/DeepWelltodoSequences)

Do similar for extracting `room_type` counts (can you figure it out?)

**NOTE** if your php version does not support `functions` you can use [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)  to dynamically create function to extract appropriate field from `room` Object or even better simply count the frequencies using a custom `foreach` loop (can you figure it out?)

For example to simply count the frequencies **without** using `array_count_values` you can do something like the following:

```
<?php

$room_details = array(
    (object)array(
                'id' => 4508,
                'api' => 'hotelbeds',
                'room_no' => 1,
                'room_type' => 'APARTMENT ONE BEDROOM',
                'meal_type' => 'ONE ROOM',
                'updated_on' => '2019-01-16 13:03:17'
        ),

    (object)array(
                'id' => 4509,
                'room_no' => 2,
                'room_type' => 'APARTMENT TWO BEDROOM',
                'meal_type' => 'TWO ROOMS',
                'updated_on' => '2019-01-16 13:03:09'
        ),

    (object)array(
                'id' => 4510,
                'room_no' => 3,
                'room_type' => 'APARTMENT ONE BEDROOM',
                'meal_type' => 'TWO ROOMS',
                'updated_on' => '2019-01-16 13:03:38'
        ),
);

$freq = array();
foreach($room_details as $roomObj) {
    $roomType = $roomObj->room_type;
    if ( !isset($freq[$roomType]) ) $freq[$roomType] = 1;
    else $freq[$roomType]++;
}

foreach($freq as $roomType=>$count) {
   echo $count . ' x ' . $roomType . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you have to remove the `S` in room_type values and make a key without `S` e.g: `$key = str_replace("S", "", $roomDetail['room_type']);` and make a another array with result of count of the $key as follow:

```
$result = [];
foreach($room_details as $roomDetail) {
        $key = str_replace("S", "", $roomDetail['room_type']);
        echo $key;
        echo "\n";
        $result[$key] += 1;
}
print_r($result);
```

Code output:

```
Array
(
   [APARTMENT ONE BEDROOM] => 3
   [APARTMENT TWO BEDROOM] => 2
   [APARTMENT THREE BEDROOM] => 1
)
```

From this `$result` you can concatenate it as you like.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the other answers....

```
$room_details = array(
    (object)array(
            'id' => 4508,
            'api' => 'hotelbeds',
            'room_no' => 1,
            'room_type' => 'APARTMENT ONE BEDROOM',
            'meal_type' => 'ONE ROOM',
            'updated_on' => '2019-01-16 13:03:17'
        ),
        (object)array(
            'id' => 4509,
            'room_no' => 2,
            'room_type' => 'APARTMENT TWO BEDROOM',
            'meal_type' => 'TWO ROOMS',
            'updated_on' => '2019-01-16 13:03:09'
        ),
        (object)array(
            'id' => 4510,
            'room_no' => 3,
            'room_type' => 'APARTMENT ONE BEDROOMS',
            'meal_type' => 'TWO ROOMS',
            'updated_on' => '2019-01-16 13:03:38'
        ),
        (object)array(
            'id' => 4511,
            'room_no' => 3,
            'room_type' => 'APARTMENT TWO BEDROOMS',
            'meal_type' => 'TWO ROOMS',
            'updated_on' => '2019-01-16 13:03:38'
        ),
        (object)array(
            'id' => 4512,
            'room_no' => 3,
            'room_type' => 'APARTMENT THREE BEDROOMS',
            'meal_type' => 'THREE ROOMS',
            'updated_on' => '2019-01-16 13:03:38'
        ),
        (object)array(
            'id' => 4513,
            'room_no' => 3,
            'room_type' => 'APARTMENT ONE BEDROOMS',
            'meal_type' => 'ONE ROOM',
            'updated_on' => '2019-01-16 13:03:38'
        )
);
```

and to process the array

```
$rooms=$meals=[];
foreach( $room_details as $index => $obj ){
    $room = rtrim( $obj->room_type,'S');
    $meal = rtrim( $obj->meal_type,'S');

    $rooms[ $room ]=empty( $rooms[ $room ] ) ? 1 : $rooms[ $room ] + 1;
    $meals[ $meal ]=empty( $meals[ $meal ] ) ? 1 : $meals[ $meal ] + 1;
}


foreach( $rooms as $key => $count )printf('%d x %s<br />',$count,$key);
foreach( $meals as $key => $count )printf('%d x %s<br />',$count,$key);
```

outputs:

```
3 x APARTMENT ONE BEDROOM
2 x APARTMENT TWO BEDROOM
1 x APARTMENT THREE BEDROOM
2 x ONE ROOM
3 x TWO ROOM
1 x THREE ROOM
```